# nginx catchall interfering with wildcard

Tags: nginx, http-redirect, catch-all

I want to redirect www (and possibly other subdomains) to my https domain. So I wrote a rule

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This didn't work until I removed my catch all entry (pasted below). I want to drop or ignore request from no host or host that don't belong to my machine. How do I get the two rules to play nice with eachother?

```
server {
    listen          80 default_server;
    listen          [::]:80 default_server;
    listen          443 default_server;
    listen          [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name     _;

    include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    return          444;
}
```

Comment: The first server block isn't listening on 443 so a redirect to https won't work. It doesn't have to do with `catch-all` at all.

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm trying to redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (https without www) and the first block only works when the second is removed. I confirmed with a browser and curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to 443 port in the first server block and remove the `catch-all` server_name in the second server block. If `Host` header is blank or doesn't match with any server block, it'll go to `default_server` and request will be rejected.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen          80 default_server;
    listen          [::]:80 default_server;
    listen          443 default_server;
    listen          [::]:443 default_server;

    include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    return          444;
}
```